# Protobuf TimeStamp UTC

Tags: c#, timestamp, utc, protobuf-net

I try to map `EF` model with `Protobuff` model:

### EF model

```
[Table("entries")]
public class Entry
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Uid { get; set; }
    public string Ip { get; set; }
    public DateTime Entered { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Retries { get; set; } = 0;
    public Guid? TokenUid { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TokenUid")]
    public Token Token { get; set; }
}
```

### Protobuff model

```
message ProtoEntry {
  string ip = 1;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp Entered = 2;
  string code = 3;
  int32 retries = 4;
  string token = 5;
}
```

### Mapping

```
var entries = _db.Entries
                .Include(x => x.Token)
                .Where(x => x.Ip == requestWithToken.Ip || x.Token.Text == token)
                .Select(x => new ProtoEntry
                {
                    Code = x.Code,
                    Entered = DateTime.SpecifyKind(x.Entered, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToTimestamp(),
                    Ip = x.Ip,
                    Retries = x.Retries,
                    Token = x.Token.Text
                }).ToList();
```

But It throws an exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Conversion from DateTime to Timestamp requires the DateTime kind to be Utc (Parameter 'dateTime')
```

I also tried:
`DateTime.SpecifyKind(x.Entered.ToUniversalTime(), DateTimeKind.Utc).ToTimestamp()`

But seems it doesn't have an effect.
Can somebody help me?

## Updates:

1. Query works good.
   [image]

Comment: What is `_db`? Presumably that's an EF Core context of some kind. Is it possible that the transformation here is somehow being performed "in-database" and causing issues? I would suggest adding `.AsEnumerable()` between the `Where` and `Select` calls to ensure you're really performing the conversion locally.

Comment: @JonSkeet, oh, sorry. `_db` is an intance of EF context, which I takes via DI. Ok, I'll try.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by changing `Timestamp.FromDateTime()` to `Timestamp.FromDateTimeOffset()`.

Official Google .NET library for protobuff contains built-in extension for datetime types:

```
public static Timestamp ToTimestamp(this DateTime dateTime)
{
     return Timestamp.FromDateTime(dateTime);
}
```

which is broken for me.

Comment: Your question has the `protobuf-net` tag - are you not actually using that, and using the `Google.Protobuf` package instead? Note that the extension method *does* work when you pass in a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of `Utc` - I still suspect the problem is around how the query is being translated, and I'd expect that `AsEnumerable` would fix this. Admittedly I'd use `DateTimeOffset` anyway rather than `DateTime`...